# Null reference in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I will try to phrase this to the best of my abilities. I'm currently trying to grab a value called `Program` but I am having trouble with my LINQ query

```
Interactions = new BindableCollection<InteractionDTO>(_client.Interactions.
    Select(x => new InteractionDTO
    {         
       Id = x.Id,
       ClientName = x.Person.CorrespondenceName,
       Indepth = x.Indepth,
       Program = x.Allocations.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Interaction_Id == x.Id).Program.Value,
       Category = x.Allocations.FirstOrDefault().Category.Value,
       ActivityDate = x.ActivityDate,
       Type = x.Type,
       Subject = x.Subject,
       LoanApplicationProvided = x.LoanApplicationProvided,
       BusinessPlanProvided = x.BusinessPlanProvided
    }));
```

The error I get is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

When I comment out below it works but `Program` isn't brought through.

```
Program = x.Allocations.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Interaction_Id == x.Id).Program.Value,
Category = x.Allocations.FirstOrDefault().Category.Value
```

My goal from the LINQ query: Has to look up interactions, then get the `Program`/`CategoryID` from `InterActionAllocations` then gets the "value" from `InteractionPrograms`.

Program.cs

```
// Primary Keys -------------------------------------------------------
public int Id { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("Interaction")]
public virtual ICollection<InteractionAllocation> Allocations { get; set; }
```

InteractionAllocation.cs

```
// Associations -------------------------------------------------------
public int Interaction_Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Interaction_Id")]
public virtual Interaction Interaction { get; set; }

public int? Category_Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Category_Id")]
public InteractionCategory Category { get; set; }
```

Comment: You need to spend some time debugging. Either Allocations is null, or there isn't one with the right interaction_id, or there is but it has a null Program, or Category is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to tackle this is to store the `Program` and `Category` as intermediary result and then use the conditional operator (`?`). This works better with the `let` keyword in comprehensive syntax:

```
from i in _client.Interactions
let program = x.Allocations.Where(y => y.Interaction_Id == x.Id)
                           .Select(a => a.Program).FirstOrDefault()
let cat = x.Allocations.Select(a => a.Category).FirstOrDefault()
select new InteractionDTO
    {         
       Id = x.Id,
       ClientName = x.Person.CorrespondenceName,
       Indepth = x.Indepth,
       Program = program == null ? null : program.Value,
       Category = cat == null ? null : cat.Value,
       ActivityDate = x.ActivityDate,
       Type = x.Type,
       Subject = x.Subject,
       LoanApplicationProvided = x.LoanApplicationProvided,
       BusinessPlanProvided = x.BusinessPlanProvided
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that at least one of your interactions doesn't have a corresponding program.  You need the sub-query to support this case.  One simple way is to do the transformation of program to program value *before* calling `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Program = x.Allocations.Where(y => y.Interaction_Id == x.Id)
    .Select(y => y.Program.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault(),
```